# Generic Interface with inverse relationship

Tags: java, generics, interface

I want to create two interfaces with inverse relationships.

```
public interface Item <D extends Description,
                                        C extends Category<D,Item<D,C>>> {
    public C getCategory();
    public void setCategory(C category);}
```

I'm not sure if expression `C extends Category<D,Item<D,C>>` is correct, but at least there are no compiler errors.

```
public interface Category<D extends Description, I extends Item> {
    public List<I> getItems();
    public void setItems(List<I> items);}
```

`I extends Item` gives the warning `Item is a raw type. References to Item<D,C> should be parametrized`. I tried

```
I extends Item<D,Category<D,I>>
```

but this results in the error `Bound mismatch: The type Category<D,I> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <C extends Category<D,Item<D,C>>> of the type Item<D,C>`. How to I parametrize the interface `Category` correctly with generics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work :). I have no idea how to explain it ( i normally try to avoid doing stuff like that ) but here it goes:

```
interface Description {}

interface Item<D extends Description, I extends Item<D, I, C>, C extends Category<D, C, I>>
{
    public C getCategory();   
    public void setCategory(C category);

}

interface Category<D extends Description, C extends Category<D, C, I>, I extends Item<D, I, C>> {    
    public List<I> getItems();   
    public void setItems(List<I> items);
}

class DescriptionImpl implements Description {}

class CustomItem implements Item<DescriptionImpl, CustomItem, CustomCategory> {
    public CustomCategory getCategory() {
        return null;  
    }

    public void setCategory(CustomCategory category) {
    }
}

class CustomCategory implements Category<DescriptionImpl, CustomCategory, CustomItem> {

    public List<CustomItem> getItems() {
        return null;          }

    public void setItems(List<CustomItem> items) {
    }
}
```

Now if you do this:

```
CustomCategory customCategory = new CustomCategory();
CustomItem customItem = new CustomItem();
DescriptionImpl description = new DescriptionImpl();

customItem.getCategory();
```

the type of the category returned by the `customItem.getCategory()` is CustomCategory which i think is what you actually want.

Comment: Yea :) It's more strange to me because i can't really explain it :))

Answer (score 0):

This compiles without warnings:

```
interface Description {}

interface Item<D extends Description, C extends Category<D, Item<D, C>>> {
    public C getCategory();
    public void setCategory(C category);
}

public interface Category<D extends Description, I extends Item<D, ?>> {
    public List<I> getItems();
    public void setItems(List<I> items);
}
```

I made `I extends Item<D, ?>`. Although this has no warnings, this may cause you other problems - let me know if it does and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Since I *know* what kind of Item I have, I don't think `<?>` is what I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Take some time to read this: http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=136394&start=15&msRange=15#180733

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget about the description at first and just make some nice symmetric interfaces:

```
 interface Item<C extends Category<Item<C>>> {}

 interface Category<I extends Item<Category<I>>> {}
```

For the Descriptions, you might want two different description types for Item and Category.

On a more general note, I'm not sure your design is a good idea.  I don't know what you'll use it for, but it looks like something that will be hard to use correctly.

Also, something looks wrong with `item.setCategory(c)` since `item` is already parametrized by a category.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simplified problem

```
interface Item<C extends Container<Item<C>>>

interface Container<I extends Item<Container<I>>>
```

It doesn't work, because subtypes of `Container<Item<C>>` are quite limited - `Container<MyItem>` is not a subtype of it, just like `List<string>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`

We can relax it with wildcards:

```
interface Item<C extends Container<? extends Item<C>>>

interface Container<I extends Item<? extends Container<I>>>
```

Now it works fine

```
class MyItem implements Item<MyContainer>

class MyContainer implements Container<MyItem>
```

mostly. The following declaration is also allowed, but not what we intended

```
class HerItem implements Item<MyContainer>  // nooo!
```

This is because we relaxed the constraints too much. Well, it's not a really serious problem. Sure, our type system isn't as tight as we want (no type system is), but programmers would instinctively follow the intended constraints, don't go out of their ways to write bizarre stuff just because they can.

Ideally, we would want a `This` type, and our intended constraints can be expressed as

```
interface Item<C extends Container<This>>>

interface Container<I extends Item<This>>
```

Since we don't have `This`, one would attempt to approach it by a type parameter

```
interface Item<C extends Container<This, C>>, This extends Item<C, This> >

interface Container<I extends Item<This, I>, This extends Container<I, This>>
```

(or, more symmetrically

```
    interface Item<C extends Container<I, C>>, I extends Item<C, I> >

    interface Container<I extends Item<C, I>, C extends Container<I, C>>
```

)However, this is not really tight either. `This` isn't really the "this type". It's possible to

```
class HerItem implements Item<MyContainer, MyItem> // uh?
```

Once again, we must rely on programmer's discipline not to do stuff like that.